# Writing text to .txt files using actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

Writing text to .txt files using actionscript. how? i couldn't find anything about that in the internet. is that possible? for flash player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash player (the one in browsers) is run through a sandbox which prevents it from accessing or creating files on the users computer (imagine the chaos if it wasn't!), among other things.

You can store persistent data using SharedObject (but this is not readily visible to the user, only useful for storing settings etc).

The other options is to send the data to a web service which in turn would allow the user to download it. Those are your only options really.

Adobe Air is a different runtime, designed to be used for desktop applications. Eg like any program on your computer. It can do a lot more, but has to be downloaded and possibly installed before you can run it (it will not run from within a HTML page).

Comment: can you give me some info about that SharedObject?

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out Adobe AIR: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flash/quickstart/articles/building_text_editor.html

Comment: is that possible for flash player?

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible from flash player, only from air.

Comment: what does that mean? :D srsly, what's the difference?

Comment: Flash player is a broswer plugin for flash content on the Internet basically, Adobe Air is for desktop/mobile applications. This is basic stuff, man

Comment: if i have an application written for flash player, is it ok to export it as air application?

Comment: do flash player and air share libraries?